# How to make API call in flutter with header key?

Tags: flutter, dart

Suppose the host site is: :

> https://dev.xyz.com

API header key: "`x-api-key: 7462-3172-8773-3312-5819`"
To register a new user you have to call PUT method:  `{{host}}/api/customer/`
And the body is like this:

```
{"email": "test@example.net",
"password": "aabbccdd",
"Name": "John",
}
```

Now how do I accomplish this in flutter? I have searched through several tutorials and still in confusion.

Comment: Check this: https://pub.dev/packages/http If anything isn't clear from that, edit/add to your question to show what you've tried / how far you got.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53299447/flutter-http-headers

Answer (score 1):

Import the http package from dart library and alias it as http, reason for this aliasing is that you dont want to have .get() method suggestion everywhere in the file. So when you use it with http as `http.get()` it will give you suggestion for `get`, In which you can pass the parameter called headers.

Code goes as follows:

```
  import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

  url = 'YOUR_URL';
  var response = await http.get(
    url,
    headers: {HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: TOKEN}, //an example header
  );
```

In your case,

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:async';

main() async {
  String url =
      'https://dev.xyz.com';
  Map map = {
    'data': {'apikey': '7462-3172-8773-3312-5819'},
  };

  print(await apiRequest(url, map));
}

Future<String> apiRequest(String url, Map jsonMap) async {
  HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
  HttpClientRequest request = await httpClient.postUrl(Uri.parse(url));
  request.headers.set('content-type', 'application/json');
  request.add(utf8.encode(json.encode(jsonMap)));
  HttpClientResponse response = await request.close();
  // todo - you should check the response.statusCode
  String reply = await response.transform(utf8.decoder).join();
  httpClient.close();
  return reply;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need put the header on the http request. For example:

```
await put(urlApi + 'update/'+ customer.id, headers: {'token': token, 'content-type': 'application/json'},body: body);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [http](https://pub.dev/packages/http) flutter package
and your code may be like

```dart
//Declared default headers
Map<String, String> headers = {"Accept": "application/json"};
//Passing the url
      Uri url = Uri.parse("https://dev.xyz.com/api/test");
// Make the request, make sure your function has a return type of future and add async keyword in order to use await :)
      var response = await http.post(url,headers: {...headers,'Authorization':"Bearer 7462-3172-8773-3312-5819"},body:{"email": "test@example.net",
"password": "aabbccdd",
"Name": "John",
});
      print(response.body);
```

in your case if your not using `Bearer` as your auth keword You can remove the bear key word and use `x-api-key` keyword
so sample will be like

```dart
//Declared default headers
Map<String, String> headers = {"Accept": "application/json"};
//Passing the url
      Uri url = Uri.parse("https://dev.xyz.com/api/test");
// Make the request, make sure your function has a return type of future and add async keyword in order to use await :)
      var response = await http.post(url,headers: {...headers,'Authorization':"x-api-key 7462-3172-8773-3312-5819"},body:{"email": "test@example.net",
"password": "aabbccdd",
"Name": "John",
});
      print(response.body);
```