# How to generate wsse header in flutter (dart)?

Tags: flutter, wsse

I want wsse header generated in flutter like this
https://doc.oroinc.com/api/authentication/wsse/

Comment: I think this will send you in the correct direction https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53299447/flutter-http-headers

Comment: Thanks. But it doesn't. I need to create nonce, and pasword digest for header.

Answer (score 0):

have never used those APIs, but here is generalised idea which default Dart libraries and i am doing a GET here, change it according to your needs

```
  var g = await HttpClient().getUrl(url);
  g.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/vnd.api+json');
  g.headers.set('Authorization', 'WSSE profile="$usernameToken"');
  g.headers.set('X-WSSE', '''
        UsernameToken Username="$admin",
        PasswordDigest="$passworddigest",
        Created="$date",
        Nonce="$nonce"
  ''');
  var r = await g.close();
  //r is a stream
  //read the response body as string
  String body = await utf8.decodeStream(r);
```

Comment: I mean I want to generate password digest and nonce in this way https://forum.oroinc.com/oro-platform/how-do-i-questions/topic/generate-api-wss-header-for-kotlin/

Comment: the document you have mentioned tells that the authentication method you are trying to do is depreciated, and it tells you to use Oauth2, which way much easier to implement on client side

Comment: But I have the api that has wsse authentication. So need this :D